# How to fix the single address?

Tags: errors

I try to use single address to my paper, I wrote it like this:

```
            %
            % Single address.
            % ---------------
line 278    \name{Shawn Zhang, Wang Ye, and John}
line 279    \address{Department of Civil Engineering,\\
             New York University,\\
             665 Broadway, 11th Floor New York, NY 10012, U.S.A.}
```

There are errors pop up. The error says:

```
line 278 ! Undefined control sequence.\name
line 279 ! Undefined control sequence.\address
```

Can anyone help me fix the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Name and address aren't standard commands. Please show us a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: @Johannes_B, I do not understand your meaning. Can you just fix the problem and tell me how to use single address?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I am a newbie for latex.

Comment: @Shawn, you should read the link proposed by Johannes_B, since we can only guess at the question we think you're asking (rather than the question you're actually asking) without more LaTeX code.

Comment: Further to the comment by @user2768 there is nothing stopping a beginner from learning to create minimal working examples. Just read the link mentioned above. You are much more likely to get help quickly if you provide a good MWE. Questions that don't have an MWE are at risk of being closed as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to replace `\name{Shawn Zhang, Wang Ye, and John}`
with 
`\author{Shawn Zhang}\author{Wang Ye}\author{John}` (does John have a family name?), and `\address` with `\affil`. (I forget if you also need `\usepackage{authblk}` for that configuration.)

Comment: @Shawn, perhaps edit your original question so that it is self-contained, and add the solution. This will help anybody looking at this question/solution in the future.